# Making a database entity superclass

Tags: java, generics, jpa

I am using JPA for my database work and I need to create a database entity superclass which all of my table entities will extend.

Every database entity will have a primary key named `id` (which in some cases is an `int` and in some a `String`) and also a `lastUpdate` field which stores the time at which the database row was last updated (set from within the code).

**`DatabaseEntity` superclass:**

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
public class DatabaseEntity <T> {
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private T _id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date _lastUpdate;

    public T getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setId(T id) {
        _id = id;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return _lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate() {
        _lastUpdate = new Date();
    }
}
```

Anything that I am doing wrong or that I should add in the superclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have something like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass 
public class DatabaseEntity <T extends Serializable> {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private T id;

    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private Integer version;

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    } 

}
```

Links to interesting annotations

[`@MappedSuperclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)

[`@Version`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Version.html)

[`@GeneratedValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html), [`@GeneratedValue`](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2011/01/hibernatejpa-identity-generators.html)

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine for me, but such a class should be `abstract`, because it does not make sense to be able create instances of this type.

```
public abstract class DatabaseEntity <T>{
//
}
```

Making it abstract will reflect the actual abstraction of this entity.

One more thing, try to avoid `java.util.Date` as much as you can, it is just awful. You can use `Joda` time instead, or the new java date api if you using Java 8.

Comment: I will make it abstract and use the Java 8 date api, I have one question that came to mind though. Should I make the two fields protected and remove the setters and getters or should I leave it as it is? Could there be any implications in the future?

Comment: @SilliconTouch keep getters public and make the setters protected

Comment: +1 for discouraging Date @SilliconTouch If you can easily change it later, consider making everything as private as possible. This will remind you every time you access something you haven't needed yet.